# How to know if `cv::imread` takes memory layout `CHW`?

Tags: c++, opencv

How to know if `cv::imread` takes memory layout `CHW`? (C channels, H height, W width)

I use this function:

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

It would be important, if I use cuda.

Comment: cv::Mat is row major and pixel data has all the channels. This means, for the first pixel you will get the top left corner pixel and it has 3 uchar values (for BGR images at least)... then the pixel of the next column follows... something like B1 G1 R1 B2 G2 R2 and so on... then it goes to the next row

Comment: can I convert it to `float* mat`? then, I access those elements via `std::cout << mat[0] << std::endl;`

Comment: [Suggested study material](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#details). Read detailed description thoroughly and at the least skim the rest, to get a good idea how it works and what functionality is available.

Comment: @j35t3r yes and no, you can access the underlying data, but the owner of this data is the original cv::Mat... you first will have to convert it to float, and then access mat.data with a reinterpret cast of float...